# How to run tslint.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tslint

I am newbie to typescript. I have `tslint.json` file created but don't have an idea about how to run this file using command line. Please advise which command do I need to use to run this config

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`tslint.json` is TSLint configuration file. It requires either global `tslint` installation:

```
npm i -g tslint
```

In this TSLint can be executed from command line as `tslint`

Or local installation:

```
npm i tslint
```

In this case tslint should be specified in package.json scripts:

```
"scripts": { "lint": "tslint" }
```

And be executed as `npm run lint`.

As `tslint --help` says, it accepts the following commandline options:

> ```
> -c, --config:
>     The location of the configuration file that tslint will use to
>     determine which rules are activated and what options to provide
>     to the rules. If no option is specified, the config file named
>     tslint.json is used, so long as it exists in the path.
> ```

`tslint.json` from existing file structure will be used by default.